# Magento 2.3.3 Keep product view page original images

Tags: magento2.3.3

i am working on a magento 2.3.3 project, i am facing issue on product view section, on product view page images are as per configuration its cool, but when click on images, they are in same size, i mean **i want to keep small images are small and bigger one will be big after on click in popup section**, i just want to keep original image shape/size after click on it. should i remove large view images declaration >?

screenshot product view section : https://prnt.sc/q8kyn0

```
<media>
    <images module="Magento_Catalog">
        <image id="bundled_product_customization_page" type="thumbnail">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>270</height>
        </image>
        <image id="cart_cross_sell_products" type="thumbnail">
            <width>152</width>
            <height>188</height>
        </image>
        <image id="cart_page_product_thumbnail" type="small_image">
            <width>110</width>
            <height>160</height>
        </image>
        <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
        <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
        <image id="customer_account_my_tags_tag_view" type="small_image">
            <width>100</width>
            <height>100</height>
        </image>
        <image id="customer_account_product_review_page" type="image">
            <width>285</width>
            <height>285</height>
        </image>
        <image id="customer_shared_wishlist" type="small_image">
            <width>113</width>
            <height>113</height>
        </image>
        <image id="gift_messages_checkout_small_image" type="small_image">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
        <image id="gift_messages_checkout_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
            <width>100</width>
            <height>100</height>
        </image>
        <image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
            <width>78</width>
            <height>78</height>
        </image>
        <image id="new_products_content_widget_grid" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
        <image id="new_products_content_widget_list" type="small_image">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>270</height>
        </image>
        <image id="new_products_images_only_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>78</width>
            <height>78</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_base_image" type="image">
            <width>265</width>
            <height>265</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_comparison_list" type="small_image">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>270</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_image_large" type="image"/>
        <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
            <width>700</width>
            <height>700</height>
            <frame>true</frame>
            <aspect_ratio>false</aspect_ratio>

        </image>
        <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
            <width>90</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
            <width>700</width>
            <height>700</height>
            <frame>true</frame>
            <aspect_ratio>false</aspect_ratio>

        </image>
        <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
            <width>700</width>
            <height>700</height>
            <frame>true</frame>
            <aspect_ratio>false</aspect_ratio>

        </image>
        <image id="product_page_more_views" type="thumbnail">
            <width>90</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_stock_alert_email_product_image" type="small_image">
            <width>76</width>
            <height>76</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_small_image" type="small_image">
            <width>135</width>
            <height>135</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_thumbnail_image" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_compared_products_grid_content_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_compared_products_images_names_widget" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_compared_products_images_only_widget" type="thumbnail">
            <width>76</width>
            <height>76</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_compared_products_list_content_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>207</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_viewed_products_grid_content_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_viewed_products_images_names_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_viewed_products_images_only_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>76</width>
            <height>76</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_viewed_products_list_content_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>270</height>
        </image>
        <image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>270</height>
        </image>
        <image id="review_page_product_image" type="small_image">
            <width>285</width>
            <height>285</height>
        </image>
        <image id="rss_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
        <image id="sendfriend_small_image" type="small_image">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
        <image id="shared_wishlist_email" type="small_image">
            <width>135</width>
            <height>135</height>
        </image>
        <image id="side_column_widget_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="upsell_products_list" type="small_image">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>270</height>
        </image>
        <image id="wishlist_sidebar_block" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="wishlist_small_image" type="small_image">
            <width>113</width>
            <height>113</height>
        </image>
        <image id="wishlist_thumbnail" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
    </images>
</media>
```